# Open the recent log file using VB script

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a VBScript function in an HTML file, as below, where I am trying to open a log file in my C: drive.

The log files are generated on a daily basis and I want to open only the one which is created today upon click of a button. The file names are with a date stamp as:  `24Jun2014.log`, `25June2014.log`

Can anyone suggest how can I get the recent file only based on the above date stamp in the log file name and open it for my below code?

VBScript to open log file

```
<script type="text/Vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim File
File = "C:\24Jun2014.log"
'***********************************************************

Function LogOpen()
    Dim Ws,iReturn,strError
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    iReturn = Ws.Run(File,1,False)
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        strError = "<b><font color=Red>The file "& File &" dosen't exists !</font></b>"
        myDiv.InnerHTML = strError
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
'***********************************************************
</script>
```

HTML to click and open the log file:

```
<div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1">
  <h2>Application log</h2>
  <center><input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="Application LogFile" onclick="LogOpen()">
</div>
```

**Date Creator property**

```
Function ShowFileInfo(filespec)
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFile(filespec)
   ShowFileInfo = "Created: " & f.DateCreated
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't derive the file spec from the current date -

```
>> d = Date()
>> WScript.Echo Day(d) & MonthName(Month(d)) & Year(d)
>> WScript.Echo Day(d) & MonthName(Month(d), True) & Year(d)
>>
25June2014
25Jun2014
```

you'll have to loop over the folder's .Files and check the .DateCreated property of each file.

Comment: I have my files in C: drive only , as you suggested I checked the datecreated property file now and added a code snippet in my original post. But in my case I need to check the files as per the names which has the date stamp in itself. I don't need the system properties. My code can handle the file names and can name it according to the dates as date.log so I need to read this text 25Jun2014 or 24Jun2014 and then have to display it as per the recent ones. Can you give me any suggestions in that context.